# HttpClient returning TaskCanceledException without calling the service in .NET Core 6 using Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, httpclient, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a .NET Core 6 web application  that is calling some external dependencies and all those dependencies are called using various `HttpClient` objects created using the `HttpClientFactory` like the following:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient("ClientName", (sp, c) =>
    {
      c.BaseAddress = new Uri("myurl");
      c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // the assumption is that the request should take less than that
    })
    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
```

This microservice is containerized using Docker (on Linux machines) and hosted in an AWS cluster using k8s as an orchestrator.

Now, the application mostly works as expected but sometimes I see in the DataDog logs that the client is returning the infamous `TaskCanceledException` and I know that this is usually related to timeouts or network-related issues.

Anyway, I see some strange behaviours I don't really understand:

- the timeout I set is not respected, in fact in the APM I see several calls taking more than the configured 10 seconds
- when we receive those errors, the destination service is not even called, in fact I don't see incoming requests
- usually those external services respond in microseconds, so it's very unlikely that they can timeout and anyway I don't see any error related to them in the logs

So, apparently, the application is returning clustered timeouts without even calling the service.

I've read a lot of articles about this and some related problems, but honestly I couldn't find anything that could solve this problem.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `.Result` or `.Wait` anywhere on your code, it might be an async deadlock

Comment: No, in this case we are awaiting the result in an async method.